# How to verify the dates are displayed correctly from array by ascending and descending order

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have captured the dates from array by using below code, and I need a help how I can verify the displayed dates are displayed correctly in ascending and descending order.

```
  await mailbox.mailbox_mailboxlist.map(async(ele) => {
    if (ele != undefined) {
        ele.getText().then((text)=> {
            //console.log(text);
            let x = text.split("\n");
            console.log("Dates  :"+x[2]);

        });
    }
})
```

Console output:

```
Dates  :Wed 30 Dec 2020 10.59am
Dates  :Wed 30 Dec 2020 10.59am
Dates  :Tue 29 Dec 2020 3.18pm
Dates  :Thu 22 Oct 2020 10.47am
```

And my next validation is to verify the above dates are displayed in ascending order .

Comment: You can use built-in javascript [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function

Comment: Hi @Soheb,thank you for your response.I am new to protractor and typescript.can you give your inputs in more details.For example date: Wed 30 Dec 2020 10.59am i need to compare with todays date and date:Tue 29 Dec 2020 3.18pm i need to compare with previous date(Wed 30 Dec 2020 10.59am).

Comment: It would be nice to know the role of `array`.